# SQL Server: Why is the backup speed so slow?

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, database-backups

I have a backup query like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE @temp_baza TO DISK = @temp_bak
BACKUP LOG @temp_baza TO DISK = @temp_log
```

It is run by sqlcmd like this:

```
sqlcmd -l 120 -S %SQL_SERVER% -i %KOPIA_KATALOG%backupPELNY.sql 
       -o %KOPIA_KATALOG%output_PELNY.txt -v NAZWA_BAZY="%NAZWA_BAZY%" 
       -v KOPIA="%PELNY_KOPIA%\"
```

In `output_PELNY.txt` I have this kind of results:

```
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 645127 pages in 2819.651 seconds (**1.787 MB/sec**).
```

or

```
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 26338 pages in 227.348 seconds (**0.905 MB/sec**).
```

Main DB is on one Disc, backup is on second disk.

When I use Explorer to copy files between these two disks, I get a transfer speed of approximately 100 MB/s.

**QUESTION:**

Why is the backup speed so slow - I mean less than 3MB/s?

**REMARKS:**

- Windows 2012 Essential  + SQL Server 2008 R2 EXPRESS
- Intel XEON E3-1270 v3  + 16GB RAM

Comment: If you run a backup using SSMS (the gui) does it have the same speed issues?  Is there a setting for backup compression or encryption turned on by default?  Since you have 100 MB/s disk is it CPU bound during backup?  How much RAM is actually available during backup, i.e. bounce the service and try backing up.  These are just some ideas.

Comment: ...
I was trying to check if it is releated to CPU so I just used 7za v18.5.0.0 to check how this will zipping 1GB file.
So to testing I use Open Hardware Monitor 
And here is what I can say:
this CPU is never use more than 50% of single CORE and never goes up above 1.8GHz where maximus is 3,7GHz
CPU Temp is about 49 Celcius 
FAN SPEED is about 6000 RPM
is it overheated ?

Comment: There is no compression or encryption .
On this system there is 16GB RAM at all, and about 50% is free.

Comment: Currently I have upgraded system with SQL 2017 Express
If I use SSMS (GUI) then in Windows Performance Monitor I get  7MB/s Read + 7MB/s Write speed per this backuped file....

At the same time processor utilization was about 1% and the processor clock was only 0,7 Ghz.

So I test if there is something wrong with my CPU.

How I do the test ?
In time when the backup is doing their job wiht SSMS , and the processor was used only 1% I run 7Zip with LZM2 and 8 Threads,

The CPU was automaticaly rise to 90% and 3,3GHz.

Comment: I'd take a quick look at your CPU setting in SQL: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15264.configuring-sql-server-cpu-utilization.aspx  and make sure something hasn't been limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem, please refer to the following links:

1. [Options to Improve SQL Server Backup Performance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2539/options-to-improve-sql-server-backup-performance/)
2. [Is your SQL Server backup running slow? Here’s how you can speed it up](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/speedup-sql-server-backup-performance/)
3. [Super-Fast Backup and Restore Throughput for SQL Server](https://blog.purestorage.com/purely-technical/super-fast-backup-and-restore-sql-server/)
4. [MS SQL Server backup optimization](https://www.sqlshack.com/ms-sql-server-backup-optimization/)
5. [How to Make SQL Server Backups Go Faster](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/how-to-make-sql-server-backups-go-faster/)

Below are some sample queries for [download](https://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages2/2539_Backup_scripts.zip)

To solve the problem, I suggest that the following part of the query:

```
backup database DBNAME to disk='C:\1\DBNAME.bak' with buffercount=16 ,maxtransfersize=4194304
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 R2 Express has the following limitations:

- Constrained to a single CPU (this limitation was raised in 2012 to "The lesser of one socket or four cores", so multi-threading is possible)
- 1GB RAM
- 10GB database size (per database)

**So your backup is likely to be CPU bound and/or memory bound.**

(Of course, it raises the obvious question: Why are you using an express version on your server? and why not a later SQL Server version?)

Ref.: [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Database Size Limit Increased to 10GB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2010/04/21/sql-server-2008-r2-express-database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb/):

> What about CPU and memory limits? Are any other limits changed in SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 Express?
>
> - No, the database size limit is the only limit we updated in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.  **SQL Server 2008 R2 Express is still limited
>     to 1 CPU and 1 GB of RAM.**

Comment: After upgrade to SQL 2017 Express there is no change in the backup speed.

Comment: I had an other case when after trying MS SQL EVALUTATION problem is gone.

Comment: I still have a few cases of this type.
Interestingly, that in one case we added new disks, for a new RAID1 matrix.
This was 2x500 GB SSD disc. The interesting thing was that the RAID INITIALIZATION PROCESS was really very slow ...... I mean 1% per 10 minutes. And I think it is somehow related.